# Unexpected end of file in gzip, but only from within script

Tags: bash, gzip

I am encountering a weird error. I have a bash script which calls a C++ program that simulates numeric values, separated by newlines (std::endl), and outputs them to stdout. This was piped through gzip, creating a file sample.csv.gz. From the same script, on the same machine, I call

```
gunzip -k -c sample.csv.gz | myprog
```

and get

```
gzip: sample.csv.gz: unexpected end of file
```

I think this shouldn't be due to the end-of-line issue often encountered, since it is the same machine and OS. Also, if I copy-and-paste the same line directly to the bash, it runs without problems. I've also checked

```
gunzip -k -c sample.csv.gz | wc -l
```

and no lines are missing. What could be causing this?

Comment: Is `gunzip < sample.csv.gz | ./myprog` any different?

Comment: Yes, in that it says "gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file" ;-)